# How can I Fix the float value in output in C language

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I have output like this:

```
1569.3669
15968.3699
41.3878
587.5401
```

but I want the output like this:

```
01569.3669
15968.3699
00041.3878
00587.5401
```

How can I do this in the C language?

Comment: If you're asking about C, don't tag it C++. You will not get correct answers.

Comment: Are you coding in C as your question states, or C++ as your tag suggests?  If the former, `man printf`.  If the latter, check documentation for &lt;iomanip&gt;.

Comment: I assumed he meant C, as in the question, and simply tagged it C++ because of the auto-completing tags (C++ is probably more popular than C on this site), so I edited the tags to be C-related. If this was incorrect, we can always fix it.

Answer (score 7):

```
printf("%010.4f", val);
```

Should do it for you, where val is each value. For more info see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#printf_format_placeholders)

Edit: Thanks Barry.

Comment: Using a leading zero is the correct idea, but the number to the left of the decimal point is the width of the entire number (integer plus decimal portion, including the decimal point itself). The correct format code is %010.4f